# Intermittent air in water lines from well - submersible pump

Tags: well, well-pump

Two weeks ago, I noticed air in our water line.  It came mostly in small spurts but greatly increased when the toilets were filling.

The plumber suspected the check valve at the submersible pump.  He pulled the pump, but everything was fine.  He then tested the well lines by pressurizing with air and noted no leaks.  Pitless was replaced 1 1/2 years ago, and no wet areas were observed around the well head.  The plumber is comfortable that it is fine.

He checked out the pressure tank, and determined everything  looked and functioned properly. It maintains 20psi.  The tank fills and there is no drop  in pressure without water usage.

He then attempted to check the line from the well head to the tank and advised that he was able to  pressurize with air, and that once removed, pressure dropped quickly.  He attempted a second time to fill, and was unable to do so.  With that, he advised that the problem must be line between wellhead and house which will require digging up my front yard.

After he left, I had no air in lines for over two days, but the problem returned, mainly at the toilets as they are filling.  (In the interim, a friend thought could be issue with hot water heater and bad thermostat--so checked that out....sounds crazy but feasible...nothing there).

They are coming to dig up my yard in a couple of days, Today, I am having no issues with air in the line.   The lumber is trustworthy, but I am extremely stressed with digging up my yard and not being close to 100% sure if that is the problem.  Has anyone ever experienced this issue?

Comment: Have you been watering your yard or garden? I am wondering if your water level in the well is dropping enough that the pump itself is picking up the air. I would expect a wet spot if the line was the problem between the well and the house.

Comment: Yes. You'd likely have a small "pond" between the well and house if there's a sizable leak.

Answer (score 1):

A water pipe under suction that has a leak will draw air in. A pressurized pipe with a leak will force water out. A submersible pump is, or should be, beneath the water and the pipe connected to it should be pressurized, so any leak in that pipe would leak water out. A low water level in the well can allow air to be drawn in with water, and can be intermittent as the water level fluctuates in the well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking ( and I am not a plumber ) any plumbing line which develops air in it, does so when a line is interupted with air via draining the system, causing a lack of water.. until the source is resupplied with water and re-established.

The only thing that comes to mind is shutting off a water supply to a residence, then opening a valve in the residence, then closing it again... After this, if one turns the water supply back on in the residence, then opens up any valve in the residence to run water, there's going to be a lot of air for a while...

Digging up your lines to check them is expensive and time consuming, but necessary. Obviously, if there's a break in that line, it "should" show with a wet spot on the property.

Good luck